# ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender losses data @ postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, calendar

Frens,

i have a textbox with ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender which losses data when i chose radio buttons ....
please read my code...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnl_Select_File_Format" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="input-field-box-container">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" runat="server" 
            SkinID="FormInputTextBox" ReadOnly="true"
            ValidationGroup="PublishUser"> </asp:TextBox>
      <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ajax_Expiry_Date" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtExpiryDate">
      </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
     </div>
     <div class="input-field-box-container">
      <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnEnabled" GroupName="Print" Text="Enable" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnCheckedChanged="rbtnEnabled_CheckedChanged" CssClass="checkbox-auto"
            Width="220px" />
      <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnDisabled" 
            GroupName="Print" Text="Disable" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnDisabled_CheckedChanged" CssClass="checkbox-auto"
            Width="220px" />
    </div>
 </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreate" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ajax_Expiry_Date" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: i cant post my coding :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radioButton's `AutoPostback` attribute(or what it is called) is true that means when you change the choice of radio button the page will post back and which will cause to refresh the UpdatePanel.As long as your radio button and CalenderExtender is on the same UpdatePanel every time `OnCheckedChanged="rbtnDisabled_CheckedChanged"` works CalenderExtender will loose data.

Well you can understand that your solution is using different `UpdatePanel`s for those `RadioButton`s and `CalenderExtender`s.

Comment: fine :)...shall i proceed with UpdatePanel inside a update panel...is it a gud practice.....

Comment: Well, I have used an UpdatePanel in an UpdatePanel and it did not cause anything bad yet.However, in your situation you do not have to do that unless you wan't to update the CalenderExtender when the choice of RadioButton changes.Therefore, you can just finish this UpdatePanel before `<div class="input-field-box-container">` and start another UpdatePanel.

Comment: i gotta very simple solution....

remove ReadOnly="true" and enjoy :)..........

shankar.m

Answer (score 0):

The solution I arrived at was to remove `ReadOnly="true"`.